# How to Recognize image in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ocr

i wanna ask that , is there any api to recognize image?

i need read data from image...can i read numbers which is printed on image..

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though there is no built in function for OCR and this would have to be a custom aspect not found in foundation.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can always download an open-sourced, external library (package) to do the OCR. [GOCR](http://jocr.sourceforge.net/) is one example.

Answer (score 0):

There are many OCR libraries  available for reading text from an image. You can check my answer [Mobile OCR Engine for iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722269/mobile-ocr-engine-for-iphone-app/15950144#15950144)

and for reading numbers only check my answer [How to read numbers only in an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607827/are-there-any-handwriting-recognition-libraries-available-for-the-iphone/15950567#15950567)

Hope it helps you.