# Search a photo for drawing

Tags: iphone, search, camera, image, cgcontext

I want to be able to do something like take a picture of a chalkboard and search for what the teacher wrote and then delete the chalkboard and make like a CGContext Path of what the teacher wrote, or just have what the teacher wrote

Comment: Please tell me why my question was thumbs downed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OCR is tricky with the iPhone camera.  If you just want to pull out edges and save those you might try a Canny edge detector followed by a little edge linking to get larger features.  You'll get some noise though, off a chalk board.

Easiest approach to that would be to use OpenCV.  You can grab a version that's already been ported and compiled from this guy's site:
http://niw.at/articles/2009/03/14/using-opencv-on-iphone/en

My sense is that this approach is probably not quite right for what you want.  I'd sit down and think a bit more about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Is it free and can I sell my app with openCV in it?

Comment: The license is fairly friendly.  I don't see why not.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at OCR.

Here is one option:
[Mobile OCR Engine for iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722269/mobile-ocr-engine-for-iphone-app)

Comment: OCR - Optical Character Recognition.

Comment: OCR is a technology to detect text in an image and convert it to text.