# iPhone: Regarding OCR technology?

Tags: iphone, ocr

I know about OCR technology. I have seen in websites saying that iPhone Camera supports OCR technology. May i know how do i handle it in my code? Is there any classes provided by SDK to support it?

Thank you.

Comment: I have described some  OCR libraries check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722269/mobile-ocr-engine-for-iphone-app/15950144#15950144)

Answer (score 3):

This works for iPhone OCR.
http://robertcarlsen.net/dev/pocket-ocr

Answer (score 0):

I would look at iqengines.com.  They have an amazing engine and a nice API.  I wrote a wrapper for the API and posted it at Github [here](http://github.com/appempire/IQEngines)