# how to read numbers in image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have used the library for reading barcode from image. But can't find any source or help for reading numbers from image.

I just need to take photo with camera and then process image whether any numbers exist and read out the numbers.

Is there any way to get the number written on image?

Comment: have you tried looking for text recognition solutions?

Answer (score 0):

that's OCR type of problem. you might want to take a look at: [Is there any good OCR API for iPhone and/or Android phones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741284/is-there-any-good-ocr-api-for-iphone-and-or-android-phones) or [iPhone: Regarding OCR technology?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341076/iphone-regarding-ocr-technology)

Answer (score 0):

The Google Docs API has some OCR support.  You may want to take a look at this and see if you can implement it: http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/09/google-docs-ocr.html I don't remember if Apple will allow you to use any external libraries though.