# How we can get value from image in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone: Regarding OCR technology?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341076/iphone-regarding-ocr-technology)

i am working on a lottery  app. where my need is to scan the image and get  printed text value of each text.[image]

i want to get following details:
07 16 27 29 45

PRICE: $20.00
DRAW: MON 26/3/2012

i am not able to get correct value

Comment: That's called "Optical Character Recognition": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition and questions about OCR have been asked here before...

Comment: That's a pretty cool idea. I suppose I could just code this up in a day and publish it to the store!

Answer (score -1):

You might need some OCR framework like e.g. http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/ (edit: Objective-C wrapper for Tesseract: https://github.com/ldiqual/tesseract-ios)

There might be better solutions, though. Google is your friend !