# I want to implement the OCR in my iPhone app

Tags: iphone

I am new in iPhone app development. I have to implement the OCR in my iPhone app. Is there any free API for implementing the OCR in iPhone app? I have found ABBYY API for it but it is not free. Please suggest me regarding it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: See my answer [Mobile OCR Engine for iPhone app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722269/mobile-ocr-engine-for-iphone-app/15950144#15950144)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964181/is-there-any-open-source-ocr-project-for-the-iphone-out-there