# Are there any handwriting recognition libraries available for the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ocr

I am looking for a simple (preferably open source) handwriting recognition library for the iPhone/iPad.  In my case, I'm only interested in recognizing numbers.

Does anyone know of a good library for this?

Comment: You will get more attention and possibly more answers if you put a little more effort into your question. Writing the title in ALL CAPS isn't going to get more people to look at it.

Comment: for a closed source solution, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196576/is-there-an-handwriting-recognition-library-for-ios/7242727#7242727

Comment: @Jasarien Actually, it does :(

Answer (score 3):

You would have to make some efforts to compile but Tesseract is good solution.

For compiling it look http://iphone.olipion.com/cross-compilation/tesseract-ocr. For sample application see http://robertcarlsen.net/tag/tesseract

Comment: I don't think tesseract is good for handwriting recognition because it's too heavy for something like recognizing the numbers.

Answer (score 2):

There are many libraries available for extracting text from images. [You can check my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722269/mobile-ocr-engine-for-iphone-app/15950144#15950144)

For restricting OCR to provide numbers only Tesseract SDK provides method as **blacklist** and **whitelist** characters

```
_tesseract->SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789");
```

Using this method you can restrict only numbers to be recognized.

Hope it helps.