# Is there an handwriting recognition library for IOS?

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there an handwriting recognition library for IOS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any handwriting recognition libraries available for the iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607827/are-there-any-handwriting-recognition-libraries-available-for-the-iphone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

came across an interesting link:
http://iphone.olipion.com/cross-compilation/tesseract-ocr

i would update on my progress

Comment: Honestly handwriting recognition is not the same as ocr although they're using similar technology. The tesseract-ocr used for the handwriting recognition is not acceptable because it's too slow.

Answer (score 7):

**Shameless plug**

[MyScript](http://myscript.com/), the company I work for licenses closed-source handwriting recognition technology for desktops (windows, linux, osx), tablets(ios, android) as well as automotive (Audi navigation system).

Our [developer portal](https://dev.myscript.com/) is regularly updated with new content.

You can try our technology on our [web demonstration portal](http://webdemo.myscript.com/) (beware some version of the Evernote clipper severely break HTML canvas interaction).

We also have various applications available on iTunes for iOS devices and Google Play for Android devices.

Hope that helps.

Comment: could you reveal in which price range the mobile SDK is based? Is it suggestive for a small company (with maybe only in-house distribution). Lets say below or above 100$/€?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not in a position to discuss pricing

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

None provided by Apple at all and none by third parties that I can find in a Google search.

Comment: I'm sorry but this answer is wrong :) Shameless plug: Vision Objects provides handwriting recognition technology for desktops (windows, linux, osx), tablets (ios, android) as well as automotive.

Comment: Well, technically it's exactly right: Apple provides no such API and I couldn't, in fact, find anything relevant on Google. You should invest some time in SEO. ;-)

Comment: You're so right about SEO :( Hence my answer and comment :/ And about Apple APIs indeed they don't want to provide an input method framework mainly because they don't want foreign code to mess with application code

Answer (score 0):

could port this to iOS...supposed to work on MacOSX

http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/

Comment: oops, I didnt see duplicate link! gives a bit of help with the cross compilation...

Comment: Yes I use already this library but cross-compiling is hard for me, I arrive to build but just the simulator can read my app, I'm lost for understanding armv6 armv7 x86 building. Thank you