# How does handwriting recognition apps for the iOS recognize my handwriting?

Tags: iphone, ios, ocr, gesture-recognition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an handwriting recognition library for IOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196576/is-there-an-handwriting-recognition-library-for-ios)

I'm building an app for the iPad that can recognize handwriting and I was wandering if there is library/framework for doing that?

Does someone knows how does the other apps do that? do they use OCR or Gesture recognition?

I know that there are many questions here about that subject but I haven't came across a satisfying answer.

Thanks.

Comment: As I said, the given answers were not satisfying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tested a lot of HWR/OCR libs.

Here are great handwriting-recognition libs:
http://www.hanvon.com/en/products/index.html
http://www.phatware.com/index.php?q=product/details/developer/writepadsdk
But they are closed-source.

Here is simple opensource one:
http://risujin.org/cellwriter/

As for me, best of OCR engines is Tesseract; it recognizes text better then even ABBYY.

Comment: i am using ABBYY ,can you share a working sample demo for tesseract?i downloaded from google but there are lots of errors in that