# Draw and detect numeric value iPhone, in need of an example without cocoa framework

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to make an application which detects numeric values drawn by user onto an iphone screen, only numeric values are considered by the application.

For example, suppose in iPhone screen I draw 1 (numeric value). Then it will give me an alert with 1 (numeric value). I am able to draw on iphone screen but enable to detect which number is drawn onto the screen.

Please help me out, I have searched more on google but couldn't found anything...
Thanks All in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a solution, but it would cost you (or your client) a licensing fee.

Check out answer # 2 (regarding [VisionObjects](http://www.visionobjects.com/)) [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196576/is-there-an-handwriting-recognition-library-for-ios).

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer, as [answers that are mostly just links are not considered "good" answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Answer (score 0):

see core graphics tutorial and also see quartz core demo