# How to recognize/detect characters in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, gesture-recognition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any handwriting recognition libraries available for the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607827/are-there-any-handwriting-recognition-libraries-available-for-the-iphone)

I have already searched a lot over for character recognization.
My problem is: I need to detect the characters like "A","Q","E","H" on finger movement for the iphone app. 
Please some one direct me to achieve this.
Or i've to use different mechanism for this.

Comment: But it doesnt give me a proper solution????
the above problem works fine with android Gesture builder and i am looking same for ios.
the ocr is for image recognisation. is there any thing like android Gesture Builder in iOS.

Comment: Try this -https://github.com/robmathews/OCR-iOS-Example